# my view gives 404 error even that post with that slug exists

Tags: python, django

Before this does not happened but after installing django-contrib-comments app, when I click on a post detail link to get post I get 404 error. But in shell there is no problem

my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^(?P<type>\w+)/(?P<slug>[\w|\W]+)/$', views.included_posts,
                                            name="included_posts"),
url(r'^post/(?P<slug>[\w|\W]+)/$', views.detail, name="detail"),
url(r'^paginated-tags/$', views.listing, name="listing"),
)
```

my views.py:

```
def detail(request, slug):
    posts = Post.published_posts.all()
    post = get_object_or_404(posts, slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'blog/index.html', {'post': post})
```

**published_posts** is my custom manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `included_posts` url catches the `post/someslug` url before the `detail` url.

Move the `included_posts` at the end of the `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<slug>[\w|\W]+)/$', views.detail, name="detail"),
    url(r'^paginated-tags/$', views.listing, name="listing"),
    url(r'^(?P<type>\w+)/(?P<slug>[\w|\W]+)/$', views.included_posts,
                                                name="included_posts"),
)
```

As side note: `([\w-]+)` is the common regex for slugs. Your `([\w|\W]+)` will match any string (for example: `"some () nonslug [] chars"`)

Comment: one more thing about **django.utils.text.slugify**. slugify('ı ü ş ö ç ğ') gives me u-s-o-c-g. I wonder why 'ı' charachter dissapears.

Comment: `slugify` uses the `unicodedata.normalize()` function which has the following issue: http://bugs.python.org/issue12846

Comment: You can use the `unicode_tr` library to slugify turkish letters: https://github.com/emre/unicode_tr#extras